# How to prevent R from rounding in frequency function?

Tags: r

I used the freq function of frequency package to get frequency percent on my dataset$MoriskyAdherence, then R gives me percent values with rounding. I need more decimal places.

```
MoriskyAdherence=dataset$MoriskyAdherence
freq(MoriskyAdherence)
```

The result is:

[image: the result]

The Percent values are 35.5, 41.3,23.8. The sum of them is 100.1. 
The exact amounts should be 35.5, 41.25, 23.75.

What should I do?
I used sprintf, as.data.frame,formatC, and some other function to deal with it.But...

Comment: Help others help you; provide a [mcve]. More specifically, consider the `r` tag info: "Please provide minimal and reproducible example(s) along with the desired output. Use `dput()` for data and specify all non-base packages with `library()` calls." Are you using `freq` from the `frequency`, `questionr`, or `summarytools` package? Something else? We don't have access to your data. Also, you say you used `sprintf()`, etc., "But....", but you don't tell us what went wrong with those attempts (or showed us how you tried those attempt). Hard to help without all the info.

Comment: Ok dear duckmayr. I will edit it

Answer (score 1):

The function `freq` returns a character data frame, and has no option to adjust the number of decimal places. However, it is easy to recreate the table however you want it. For example, I have written this function, which will give you the same result but with two decimal places instead of one:

```r
freq2 <- function(data_frame)
{
  df <- frequency::freq(data_frame)
  lapply(df, function(x) 
  {
    n                      <- suppressWarnings(as.numeric(x$Freq))
    sum_all                <- as.numeric(x$Freq[nrow(x)])
    raw_percent            <- suppressWarnings(100 * n / sum_all)
    t_row                  <- grep("Total", x[,2])[1]
    valid_percent          <- suppressWarnings(100*n / as.numeric(x$Freq[t_row]))
    x$Percent              <- format(round(raw_percent, 2), nsmall = 2)
    x$'Valid Percent'      <- format(round(valid_percent, 2), nsmall = 2)
    x$'Cumulative Percent' <- format(round(cumsum(valid_percent), 2), nsmall = 2)
    x$'Cumulative Percent'[t_row:nrow(x)] <- ""
    x$'Valid Percent'[(t_row + 1):nrow(x)] <- ""
    return(x)
  })
}
```

Now instead of

```r
freq(MoriskyAdherence)
#> Building tables
#>   |===========================================================================| 100%
#> $`x:`
#>                           x label Freq Percent Valid Percent Cumulative Percent
#> 2    Valid   High Adherence         56    35.0          35.0               35.0
#> 3             Low Adherence         66    41.3          41.3               76.3
#> 4          Medium Adherence         38    23.8          23.8              100.0
#> 41                    Total        160   100.0         100.0                   
#> 1  Missing          <blank>          0     0.0                                 
#> 5                      <NA>          0     0.0                                 
#> 7                     Total        160   100.0
```

you can do

```r
freq2(MoriskyAdherence)
#> Building tables
#>   |===========================================================================| 100%
#> $`x:`
#>                           x label Freq Percent Valid Percent Cumulative Percent
#> 2    Valid   High Adherence         56   35.00         35.00              35.00
#> 3             Low Adherence         66   41.25         41.25              76.25
#> 4          Medium Adherence         38   23.75         23.75             100.00
#> 41                    Total        160  100.00        100.00                   
#> 1  Missing          <blank>          0    0.00                                 
#> 5                      <NA>          0    0.00                                 
#> 7                     Total        160  100.00
```

which is exactly what you were looking for.

Comment: @diana If you find this answer helpful, please consider accepting it to mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Two (potential) solutions:

**Solution #1:**

Make changes inside the function `freq`. This can be done by retrieving the function's code with the command `freq` (without round brackets), or by retrieving the code, with comments, from https://rdrr.io/github/wilcoxa/frequencies/src/R/freq.R.
My hunch is that to obtain more decimals, changes must be implemented at this point in the code:

```
# create a list of frequencies
 message("Building tables")
 all_freqs <- lapply_pb(names(x), function(y, x1 = as.data.frame(x), maxrow1 = maxrow, trim1 = trim){
 makefreqs(x1, y, maxrow1, trim1)
})
```

**Solution #2:**

If you're only after percentages with more decimals, you can use `aggregate`. Let's suppose your data has this structure: a dataframe with two variables, one numeric, one a factor by which you want to group:

```
set.seed(123)
Var1 <- sample(LETTERS[1:4], 10, replace = T)
Var2 <- sample(10:100, 10, replace = T)
df <- data.frame(Var1, Var2)
   Var1 Var2
1     B   97
2     D   51
3     B   71
4     D   62
5     D   19
6     A   91
7     C   32
8     D   13
9     C   39
10    B   96
```

Then to obtain your percentages by factor, you would use `aggregate`thus:

```
aggregate(Var2 ~ Var1, data = df, function(x) sum(x)/sum(Var2)*100)
  Var1     Var2
1    A 15.93695
2    B 46.23468
3    C 12.43433
4    D 25.39405
```

You can control the number of decimals by using `round`:

```
aggregate(Var2 ~ Var1, data = df, function(x) round(sum(x)/sum(Var2)*100,3))
```